# ORA-00936: missing expression for DELETE statement & VIEW in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle11g, scripting

I am getting the message "ORA-00936: missing expression" when I am trying to create a DELETE statement and a VIEW in Oracle 11g.

**DELETE STATEMENT**:
Here's the original table created:

```
    CREATE TABLE SHIPMENT
    (
    ShipmentID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    ShipperID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES SHIPPER(ShipperID),
    ShipperInvoiceNumber INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Origin VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
    Destination VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
    DepartureDate DATE,
    ArrivalDate DATE
    );
```

And here's the DELETE statement I want to use:

```
    DELETE SHIPMENT WHERE ShipmentID = <ShipmentID TO DELETE>;
```

**VIEW**:
Here's the view I want to create:

```
    CREATE VIEW PurchaseSummaryView AS
    SELECT PurchaseID, [Date], Description, AND PriceUSD
    FROM PURCHASE_ITEM;​
```

And this is the table created for it:

```
    CREATE TABLE PURCHASE_ITEM
    (
    PurchaseItemID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    StoreID INT NOT NULL REFERENCES STORE(StoreID),
    "Date" DATE NOT NULL,
    Description VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
    Category VARCHAR2(30),
    PriceUsed NUMBER(15, 2)
    );
```

I am not familiar with Oracle 11g as I want to be. What simple mistake am I making?

Comment: `[DATE]` is not Oracle syntax.

Comment: It might be helpful to give which line the error refer to. and in the view creating statement :                                                                                                                    
        "  CREATE VIEW PurchaseSummaryView AS
    SELECT PurchaseID, [Date], Description, AND PriceUSD
    FROM PURCHASE_ITEM;​  "        the "AND" looks weird, probably you can remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please create the view like below

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE  VIEW PurchaseSummaryView AS
 SELECT PurchaseID, "Date", Description, PriceUSD
 FROM PURCHASE_ITEM;​
```

And `delete` the statement should be fine